# Why Should I use stored procedure with out put parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Stored procedure without output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Getstudentname
    (@studentid INT   -- Input parameter, Studentid of the student
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Firstname + ' ' + Lastname 
    FROM tbl_Students 
    WHERE studentid = @studentid
END
```

I executed the above stored procedure:

```
exec Getstudentname 2
```

Result is: Pankaj Kumar

where as stored procedure with output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetstudentnameInOutputVariable
    (@studentid INT,                 -- Input parameter, Studentid of the student
     @studentname VARCHAR(200) OUT   -- Out parameter declared with the help of OUT keyword
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @studentname = Firstname + ' ' + Lastname 
    FROM tbl_Students 
    WHERE studentid = @studentid
END
```

I executed this stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[Getstudentname]
                           @studentid = 2

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Result is: Pankaj Kumar

Comment: You are sure this is Oracle ?

Comment: This is not Oracle; I suggest you remove the tag.

Comment: This is Oracle only..

Comment: @vinothkumar then its procedure will compile with error. check online how to write oralce procedure as the syntax different then sql server.

Comment: The syntax you are using is completely invalid for Oracle - that looks like T-SQL for SQL Server.  If you really successfully executed that procedure than you are most definitely **not** using Oracle

Comment: Just read the documentation - it has an example using output parameters.

Comment: Accept the best suited answer and earn reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure may not `select` anything.  Your `OUT` param could, for example, store the number of rows inserted into a programmatically created table.  That output could then be the input for a subsequent `EXEC`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to execute `GetstudentnameInOutputVariable`

```
DECLARE @return_value VARCHAR(200)

EXEC  [dbo].[Getstudentname] 2,@return_value OUTPUT

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

There can be few number of scenario where you can use `OUTPUT` paramter,your example do not seem to be one of them.

When your proc return one value which normally indicate Flag .

Like in your example,

`SELECT @studentname = Firstname + ' ' + Lastname FROM tbl_Students`

I may need to select several column from `tbl_Students` ,so `output` column is not ideal.

Say I have a proc which does DML operation and in front end application like `c#`
I want only flag to know if given proc wa executed succesfully or some validation fail or some error,I need to know only `Pass/Fail` flag and will do work based on flag.

When you do `DML operation` only then `ExecuteNonQuery` is best choice.
`Output paramter` work best with `EXecuteNonQuery`.

So you should use `Output parameter` in this siutation.

Another situation is when you execute one proc and need 1 or 2 result of that proc to work in calling proc.

Then it is very convnient way.

You can return resultset also but to catch resultset you need to create temp 
,it is little cumbersome.

Conclusion : It depend upon your real situation.